# Find joint pdf table of two discrete independent random variables $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability, random-variable, density-function, independence, joint-distribution

Given the pdfs of two discrete independent variables $X$ and $Y$, write the joint pdf. There is a property that $ if\  \  p_{XY}(x,y) = p_X(x)p_Y(y) \ \forall i,j 
 \Rightarrow \text{X,Y are independent}$. I am not that sure if this statement is true for $"\Leftarrow"$ and I cannot find another way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converse is also true and you can write the joint pmf as the multiplication of the two marginal pmfs.